# CSS component is moving up the screen to the header

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have used these CSS properties for my card, however whenever I move the page to test the responsiveness the component moves upwards towards the header.

(I would post a photo but I don't have the rep yet)

```
.card {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```
<div className="card">
        <div className="p-4  bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 shadow-md sm:p-6 lg:p-8 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 w-96 min-w-full">
          
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this with a parent div unsure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).